Entity Framework, inheritance and decoupling problem
I have a few layers in my app. My main objects are represented in 3 layers: Application, Domain, and persistence.
For example. I have a class SoccerPlayer in the Domain layer, and accordingly, I have PlayerDto and PlayerEntity.
The playerEntity is a direct extension (inheritance) of the SoccerPlayer class, with the addition of EF class attributes.
In addition to this, I have 4 DB contexts, each one to represent a group of entities:

LeagueDbContext represents all league objects
TeamDbContext represented all team object
PlayerDbContext and MatchDbContext.

Of course, there are some overlaps, as a team has a collection of players, for example.
My first problem (I have a few):
EF sometimes creates the base class tables. If I have PlayerEntity : SoccerPlayer, then EF will create both Players (taken from PlayerEntity table attribute) and SoccerPlayer (which is the PlayerEntity base class) tables.
It does it for all my classes.
WHY?
I would expect EF to use my attributes to decide which tables to create.


ensure that DbContext do not expose DbSet<SoccerPlayer> property, 2) ensure that you have not called modelbuider.Enity<SoccerPlayer>()  3) Ensure that mapped classes do not have navigation property with type SoccerPlayer. Then your base class should not be mapped to database.


You are subclass'ing "SoccerPlayer" to "add ef attributes"?  how does that work?   consider FLUENT "mappings" to separate the Entity and the mapping.  using subclass'ing to accomplish that.. feels "off".     https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx   I think this is a play on the design principal "prefer composition over inheritance"

Thanks.

ensure that DbContext do not expose DbSet property - They don't
ensure that you have not called modelbuider.Enity() - I did not
Ensure that mapped classes do not have navigation property with type SoccerPlayer. - What do you mean?


[Table("Players")]
public class SoccerPlayerEntity : SoccerPlayer
{
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public new Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public class SoccerPlayer
{
public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

....many other domain properties
}

I mean there are no classes with property of type SoccerPlayer, like public SoccerPlayer Player { get; set; }

OK,I don't have such property. EF still tries to create a table of the base class (e.g. SoccerPlayers table).
Why?
